# Trouble overriding a method in Gallery view in Android

Tags: android

OKay gang, forgive me if this question is ubernoobness, but i am having trouble overriding a couple of methods of the Gallery class in my CustomGallery class, which is extended from Gallery.  can someone tell me why this is okay to override:

```
@Override
 public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY)
 {
  return super.onFling(e1, e2, 0, velocityY);
 }
```

but this one creates an error - "The method onFinishedMovement() of type CustomGallery must override a superclass method":

```
@Override
 private void onFinishedMovement()
 {
        //
    }
```

As far as I can tell they are all members of the same class, but clearly I am missing something.  Thanks for any help understanding this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

onFinishedMovement() is private method of Gallery so it's not accessible outside the class in which it is defined ( including inherited classes)

Comment: I'm not trying to access it from outside the class.  I have written a custom gallery class that extends from Gallery.  Are you suggesting that a method must be public in order to be overwritten?

Comment: Is it not true that a class that extends from another has access to all its super class's methods and properties?

Comment: ok, i see now.  Protected and up can be overridden.  What a freakin pain!